# Is there a unicode character that makes the previous or next character invisible?

Tags: unicode, symbols

Is there a unicode character that makes the previous or next character invisible?

I found a lot of characters that somehow modify or overlap neighboring ones, but I didn't find the right one.

An example of characters interacting with others:
A๋
◌͘s

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a Unicode character that makes a preceding or following character invisible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a display that shows characters serially and can back up, the [backspace character U+0008](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0008) can be used to back over a previously displayed character and overwrite it with another.  An editor will probably reveal the character though.  It doesn't work the way a Unicode modifier would.